# Find the limit of a function with a natural logarithm

Tags: limits

How to find lim if this function:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0}(\log_{6 x} 8 x)$$

I get this and get stuck:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0}(\frac{1}{\log_{8}{6} + \log_{8}{x}} + \frac{1}{\log_{x}{6} + \log_{x}{x}})$$

Comment: Transform your first logarithm to natural base.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\log_{6x} 8x = \frac{\ln(8x)}{\ln(6x)}.$$

Now use L'Hospital.

Comment: I think a proof of L'Hospital is not so easy and it seems that this way is too much for this easy limit. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_{6 x} 8 x = \frac{\ln 8x}{\ln 6x} = \frac{\ln8+\ln x}{\ln6+\ln x} \to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the change of base formula first:

$$f(x):=\log_{6x} 8x = \frac{\ln(8x)}{\ln(6x)}$$

Then with the property $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$,

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln(8)+\ln(x)}{\ln(6)+\ln(x)}$$

Clearly, one has the following asymptotic equivalences about $0$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(8)+\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}=1 \;\;\;\;\; \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(6)+\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}=1$$

(Verification is easy, just split up the fraction and note that $1/\ln(x) \to 0$.) As a result, we can freely swap each of the numerator and denominator with $\ln(x)$ in the limit, thus meaning

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 = 1$$

---

Alternatively, as suggested by Fred in his answer, use L'Hopital's rule on

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln(8x)}{\ln(6x)}$$

This is visibly a limit of the form $-\infty/-\infty$ (if we naively let $x=0$ in the limit $x\to 0^+$). Then we get, since $(\ln(cx))' = 1/x$ for nonzero constants $c$,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 = 1$$